# Uploading and Merging images in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, image

So I'm looking to create an internal tool where our employees can upload a picture of themselves, which automatically merges it with a white border at the bottom (company logo border) and their name on top of it. This way the offices can easily print the pictures for `employee boards`

So what I need is:
- merge border, picture and text into one image.
- Upload function with crop tool.

What I found is:
- PHP Image Magician `(http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com/)`

This basically has all functions I need available so naturally I got excited but I ran across one thing:

In the `14.1_upload.php` file it refers to the following:

> require_once('image_lib/upload_class.php');

the `image_lib/upload_cass.php` file doesnt come with the download from the website.

Is there something I'm missing or would you guys recommend not to use PHP Image Magician at all?

I'm looking to make it a very basic and simple tool but functional.

Thanks a bunch in advance

Answer (score 0):

Uploading Image is a very easy process, you can use W3School reference to understand it well http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

**About Image merge you can use below code:**

```
<?php
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('vinyl.png');
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('cover2.jpg');

imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);

imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 181, 180, 100); //have to play with these numbers for it to work for you, etc.

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

Comment: first off, thanks for taking the time to reply. from your answer I'm getting the idea of uploading it first, and then run a separate script to merge it? I have found that link you sent as well and the uploading part works, but the question is how to handle it with a crop function and immediately merging it with the standard banner + text